# os.Logger (os_log) ignores the new privacy string interpolation

Tags: swift, ios14

Using the following code on a iOS 14 simulator, all the log statements are printed in clear-text.
There is no redactions or hashing happening. Both in the Xcode console, and in the Console.app on Mac.

Is anything else required to test if the redaction work?

```
let email = "apple@stackoverflow.com"
let logger = Logger()
logger.log("\(email, privacy: .auto)")
logger.log("\(email, privacy: .auto(mask: .hash))")
logger.log("\(email, privacy: .private)")
logger.log("\(email, privacy: .private(mask: .hash))")
```

Comment: This https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/oslog-unified-logging/? *“The Xcode console and the Console.app will show the data as normal **when a debugger is attached**.”*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are doing this with the simulator. It only applies when running on a physical device.

Also, the device must not be attached to the debugger.

E.g. here is the console when I watch it while connected to debugger:

[image]

When you run this code on a physical device while not connected to the debugger and watch on the macOS console, you will see:

[image]

Obviously, in the macOS Console app’s “Action” menu, make sure to turn on the “Include Info/Debug Messages” options. And, needless to say, it is for `Logger` and `OSLog` statements; `print` statements will not appear in the macOS Console.

Comment: are debug messages streamed to console when debugger is not attached? I can't seem to see them in the console while streaming and when debugger is attached

Comment: I reran the above demo and I get the exact same results now, with latest macOS and iOS versions. I.e., when attached to debugger, I see the logging results as shown in the first screen snapshot (both in macOS Console and Xcode debugger). And when running directly on device after having terminated Xcode, I see the latter results on the macOS console, with private information hidden. So, yes, debugging messages are streamed to console when debugger is not attached. It's one of the reasons we use unified logging, to get logging without Xcode debugger artificially altering the app lifecycle.

Comment: Obviously, in the Console app’s “Action” menu, make sure to turn on the “Include Info/Debug Messages” option. And, needless to say, it is for `Logger` and `OSLog` statements, not for `print` statements.

Comment: FWIW, occasionally streaming stops, so sometimes I have to exit the Console app and restart it to wake it up. It doesn't happen a lot, but occasionally.

Comment: thanks a ton!!!! “Include Info/Debug Messages” option was not turned on ... :D. Would you like to include it in the answer so that others stuck like me would also benefit from that tip