# How to use private OSLogMessage in iOS Swift Logger library?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, oslog

I was working on Logging on to iOS and decided to learn more about Logger structure in iOS, started with [Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code) which is quite well, and after [watched](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/) WWDC 2020 video about Logging, the problem is that I could not achieve to simulate the private logging as the documentation dictate or even in WWDC video did, somehow my application couldn't achieve it. I already examine the logs from the XCode terminal and the Console app with Simulator + Real Device, let me share my piece of code on logging.

```swift
let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.myname.LogExample", category: "ViewController")
let appName = "LogExample"
let numberToBePrivate = 35
logger.notice("Hello, this is default message")
logger.notice("Hello again, this is default message with private integer of \(numberToBePrivate, privacy: .private)")
logger.log("Hello, my name is \(appName, privacy: .private)")
```

And my logs, the outputs of the XCode terminal

```
2022-12-07 01:30:14.372319+0200 LogExample[62053:2356742] [ViewController] Hello, this is default message
2022-12-07 01:30:14.372816+0200 LogExample[62053:2356742] [ViewController] Hello again, this is default message with private integer of 35
2022-12-07 01:30:14.372921+0200 LogExample[62053:2356742] [ViewController] Hello, my name is LogExample
```

And in the Console app

[image]

What I expect is a total `<private>` mark on the message of set private privacy sections, which is the expected one.

As I know, the output in the Console.app for the second log should be exact like this:

```
Hello again, this is default message with private integer of <private>
```

As I said before, I tried both the simulator + real device and the behavior of the Logger is totally the same. If I am doing anything wrong, I would like to learn it or any idea which useful would be super cool.

PS: `notice` and `log` function is the same level, `notice` basically is the default log level, and when you don't describe the level in the `log` function, it is described as `default`, so they are basically the same. And they are supposed be persisted.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903401/6407127).